# Why did The Capitol need nuclear weapons?

Tags: the-hunger-games

As far as I'm aware, before they left the districts, and Panem itself – District 13 was the district of graphite and nuclear weapons, so I was wondering why The Capitol would have a need of using nuclear weapons.

I know it may be useful if there was an uprising of some sort, but wouldn't District 13 be able to use them against The Capitol itself?

Comment: the capitol needed nukes for a few reasons. first while district 13 was part of panem they had nukes, therefor the captial also needed to nukes as a method of mutual assured destruction. after district 13 leaves the capital, they still know that 13 has nukes, therefor they must keep their nukes around as well. the reasons both the capital and district 13 had nukes, is because whatever is happening outside of north america, its probably a similar situation so that means that theirs thousands of nukes around the world still that people could potentially use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the Capitol has nuclear weapons is the same reason the United States has nuclear weapons. They are a form of deterrence. If you know other people who could potentially threaten you have nuclear weapons, you must also have them to counter that threat.

District 13 had nukes, therefore the Capitol needed them as well. On top of that very little is said about the rest of the world, but we can assume that the thousands of nukes that China, Russia, and Europe have will still be out there so the Capitol needs nukes to defend against outside threats as well.

Comment: I would format it better

Comment: Deterrence against whom? It obviously did not discourage the uprising.

Comment: This answer doesn't make much sense since [Panem is, as far as anyone else in the story knows, the last human civilization on Earth.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10784/31394)